# Instant searching using the UISearchBar/UISearchController in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swift3

I am trying to add the instant search functionality into my existing controller  using the UISearchBar or 
UISearchController

- When user enters 3 characters on `searchbar`, should start fetching the data & show in the tableview. For that I added the API call on searchBar Delegate, but it takes time to fetch the data , while user again start entering the data, each time user enters a character , it hits one api.

What approach should we follow to achieve it ?

Is there any good library or open source to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [InstantSearch iOS](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch-ios/), which is an open-source library providing UI components to help you easily build instant search experiences on iOS with [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/).

It is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-ios). See for example the InstantSearch [E-commerce app](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-ios-examples/tree/master/ecommerce%20Ikea#e-commerce-application):

[image]

You can start with the [Getting Started Guide](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch-ios/getting-started.html) which will take you through the main steps to use the library.

[The example application](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-ios-examples/tree/master/ecommerce%20Ikea#e-commerce-application) is also a great addition to the guide as it’ll help you get an idea of what you can build with InstantSearch iOS.

*Disclaimer: I am the author of InstantSearch iOS*

Comment: Is there a way to use it without an Algolia Account? So for example to use the data from an array?

Comment: @JohnSmith Maybe this [custom backend tutorial](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch-ios/custom-backend.html) could be helpful to you.

Comment: I'm trying to do the searching Process on the device not on any server. So is there a way of searching through a local array or local json file without any account?

Comment: In the link I sent, you can return results from a local array/file instead of doing a network request from a server. Although, I have to admit that the costs of going through all this (and dealing with pagination etc) might be bigger than the benefits that InstantSearch can offer you in that specific case.

Comment: As far as I understood, the code shown in the link sends a request with the searchString to a custom Backend server via alamofire and then converts the jsonResponse to the input. I didn't see anything else regarding the usage without a backend -> local file